# How to launch a build pipeline on pull request

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, pull-request

I would like to have a pull request launch a build and that build must succeed before merging into the target branch is allowed.

I have master and develop branch and create feature branches from develop. work is completed  and then a pull request initiated to merge back into develop.

I have created a build pipeline that completes successfully when run manually.

I have specified in the branch policies for the develop branch that the build must be run and complete successfully.

Now when I create a pull request, it says that in order for the pull request to be approved, the build must run but it does not run the build.  What am I doing wrong?
[image]

This is a c# .net framework app.

Should I be saving the yaml in the develop branch or master?  That part confuses me.  Is the trigger correct?

This is my yaml for the build pipeline:

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

name: '1.0.1.$(Rev:r)'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- checkout: git://OvaFlow/Utilities@develop
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: VersionAssemblies@2
  inputs:
    Path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    VersionNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    InjectVersion: true
    FilenamePattern: 'AssemblyInfo.*'
    OutputVersion: 'OutputedVersion'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Utilities/packages.config'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NuGet.config'
    restoreDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/packages'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/UtilitiesTests/packages.config'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NuGet.config'
    restoreDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/packages'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Utilities.sln'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  continueOnError: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be saving the yaml in the develop branch or master? That part confuses me. Is the trigger correct?

The answer is yes! In fact, you have already found the answer.

As we know from the [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation):

> Set a policy requiring changes in a pull request to build successfully
> **with the protected branch** before the pull request can be completed.
> Build policies reduce breaks and keep your test results passing. Build
> policies help even if you're using continuous **integration (CI) on your
> development branches** to catch problems early.

So, the build validation used for the branches which you want to protected, the `.yml` should saved in the branch which you set the build policy.

As test, if I set the `.yml` file under the **Test** branch, then pull request for the `dev` branch, the build will not be triggered automatically:

[image]

Then, I moved the `.yml` file to the `dev` branch with a new build pipeline, it works fine:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll try that.  What i'm confused about is that when I merge the develop into the master, won't it attempt to merge the yml files?  Or copy across if not present in both

Comment: @TimRutter, It will merge the yml files.

Comment: so how can that work if you have a build for master and develop?  you might want to run different tests for master for example

Comment: @TimRutter, Create a `master.yaml` under the `master` branch for master build, then `develop.yaml` under `develop` branch for develop build, not use the same yml file for different builds.

Comment: ok that makes sense.  I guess you just end up with both in the master branch but thats not a big deal

Comment: i will do i just want to check it works first thanks :)

Comment: thanks that works.  I don't know why that isn't made more obvious in the documentation!  Or in the browser eg when I try and run the master.yml build for develop, the Run button is just greyed out, it should tell you why.

Comment: @TimRutter, Sure.

Answer (score 0):

If build is not configured to run automatically on push, you have to run it manually, here:
[image]

Or you can configure build to trigger automatic on branch update:

[image]

Comment: so with the "..." button, ive spotted that and clicked "Queue build" but nothing happens

Comment: also with the second option, its already set to automatic in the build policy

Comment: i think there is something fundamental Im missing here.

Comment: @TimRutter I'm not sure if it is your case, but sometimes Pull Request Policy changes does not apply to existing Pull Requests. So if you already had pending pull request and then changed build policy, it my not work correctly. You have to abandon this PR and create it again.

Comment: Can you show yours branch configuration and build policy configuration?